# Trying to disable 'required' on a field after selecting certain value on previous field in yii2

Tags: jquery, validation, yii2

i'm new to yii2 framework.

i have a form and the idea is to hide and disable 'required' on a field based on the value selected on the previous field.

i managed to hide the field using jquery but i failed to disable the 'required' one.

[image: When i select publish]
[image: When i select 'Not Publish', the announcement field hidden but when i click create button, nothing happen bacause i have to fill in value in all fields including the hidden one]

I hope anyone can help me, because it took me 2 days already and i cannot solve it.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply conditional validation for that field.  [Doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation)

Your Model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [],//other rules
        ['your_field', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
              // return true or false according to your condition
              // server side validation
        }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
              return $('#previousField').val() == 'Condition';
              // return true of false to disable or enable required condition
              // client validation
        }"]
    ];
}
```